# Recursive search and replace with PCRE

Tags: open-source, command-line, shell-scripting

Recursive search and replace with PCRE

## Features

- open source
- command line tool
- recursive search and replace in text files.
- supports PCRE like Python does.
- Installable via RPM/DPKG Ubuntu 14.04 without adding an extra package repo.
- support for interactive search+replace.
- Scripting solutions using sed, awk, ... are no solutions in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question - just use python with re, fileinput & possibly even os.walk:

- open source command line tool recursive search and replace in text
  files. **Yes**
- supports PCRE like Python does. **Yes exactly like python!**
- Installable via RPM/DPKG **Yes** *If you don't have it already*
- Ubuntu 14.04 without adding an extra package repo. *Yes*
- support for interactive search+replace. *A python script can prompt the user for missing fields.*
- Scripting solutions using sed, awk, ... are no solutions in my eyes

A starting point:

```
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
    line = re.sub('foo','bar', line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

this can even be done directly from the command line with:

`python -c "import re, fileinput;for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1, backup='.bak'):; line = re.sub('foo','bar', line.rstrip()); print(line);"` *list_of_files*

but you probably don't wish to type all of that every time. So something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
wcreplace Find and replace wildcards on input files

Usage:
wcreplace findwc replacewc file...
"""
import sys
import fileinput
import re

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print("ERROR: Not enough parameters")
    print(__doc__)
    sys.exit(1)

findwc = sys.argv[1]
replacewc = sys.argv[2]

for line in fileinput.input(sys.agv[3:], inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
    line = re.sub(findwc, replacewc, line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

Put in a file called `wcreplace`, somewhere on the path like `/usr/bin` and set to executable with `chmod 755 wcreplace` should do the job.

**Note:** The above is ***untested!*** so test before use!

Comment: Yes, this works, even on one line. Is there not solution which just takes my regex- and insert-string? I could write a python script. I know, but I would like to have something which can be installed via RPM/DPKG.

Comment: @guettli - added a rough and ready script.

Comment: Yes this works. I wrote such a script some time ago: https://github.com/guettli/reprec but I would like to have something which is already available as RPM/DPKG. I just can't believe that modern linux distributions don't contain such a tool. It this is the case, then I will package my version (what tried to avoid).